# Tornadofx2 - NativeBuild with Gluon

Tags: gluon, tornadofx, graalvm

I'm despaired with GraalVM 21 and Tornadofx2 (Java 11). As far I know, gluon should deal with it for me, as it has some specialized handling for JavaFX builds.

My Setup:
JVM: GraalVM Community Edition 21.0.0.2

```
// Should work only with GraalVM Community Edition 21.0.0.2 and higher
id 'com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin' version '0.1.36'
id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
```

Gradle commands:

```sh
gradle :clean :assemble :nativeBuild :nativeRun
```

For some reason, it's doubled. :(

```
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: Type `technology.xxx.yyy.client.view.MainView` can not be instantiated reflectively as it does not have a no-parameter constructor or the no-parameter constructor has not been added explicitly to the native image.
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(DynamicHub.java:883)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(DynamicHub.java:883)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at tornadofx.FXKt.find(FX.kt:437)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at tornadofx.FXKt.find(FX.kt:437)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at tornadofx.FXKt.find$default(FX.kt:426)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at tornadofx.FXKt.find$default(FX.kt:426)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at tornadofx.App.stop(App.kt:139)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at tornadofx.App.stop(App.kt:139)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$10(LauncherImpl.java:865)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$10(LauncherImpl.java:865)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:102)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:102)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST:Ljava_lang_Runnable_2_0002erun_00028_00029V(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST:Ljava_lang_Runnable_2_0002erun_00028_00029V(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(WinApplication.java)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(WinApplication.java)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    ... 3 more
[So. Apr. 18 14:05:13 MESZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]    ... 3 more
```

My MainApp:

```kotlin
class MyApp: App(MainView::class) {
    init {
        FX.layoutDebuggerShortcut = KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.F12)
    }

    override fun start(stage: Stage) {
        with(stage) {
            super.start(this)
            minWidth = 1920.0
            minHeight = 768.0
            //isResizable = true
            //isMaximized = true
            centerOnScreen()

            // App Icon
            val favicon = MyApp::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/icons/favicon-32x32.png")
            addStageIcon(Image(favicon))

            find(ThemeController::class).loadThemeByConfig()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            launch<MyApp>(args)
        }
    }
}
```

My MainView:

```kotlin
class MainView : View("SpaceUp - Your Uberspace tool"), WsOperation {
    private val client: Websocket.Companion.Client by inject()

    init {
        try {
            client.getWs("feedback", this)
        }catch(ex: UninitializedPropertyAccessException) {
            // NOP
            //alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,
            // "Connection Issue", "Unable to connect with Server!", ButtonType.OK)
        }
    }

    override val root = vbox {

        menubar {
            menu(messages["File"]) {
                separator()
                item(messages["File_Exit"]).action {
                    log.info("Leaving SpaceUp-Client")
                    Platform.exit()
                }
            }
            menu(messages["Extras"]) {
                item(messages["Extras_Settings"]).action {
                    // open
                    find<SettingsView>().openModal(stageStyle = StageStyle.UTILITY)
                }
            }
            menu(messages["Help"]) {
                item(messages["Help_About"])
            }
        }
        tabpane {
            tabClosingPolicy = TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE

            tab<SystemView>()
            tab<DomainView>()
            tab<ServiceView>()
        }
        toolbar {
            add(RestProgressBar::class)
            add(ConnectionFragment::class)
        }
    }

    override fun onText(data: String) {
        val feedback = Gson().fromJson(data, Feedback::class.java)

        val feedbackJsonModel = FeedbackJsonModel()
        feedbackJsonModel.info = feedback.info
        feedbackJsonModel.error = feedback.error

        fire(FeedbackEvent(feedbackJsonModel))
    }
}
```

When I try to apply

```
id 'com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin' version '0.1.38'
id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
```

I get this error:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin', version: '0.1.38']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin'.
   > Could not create task ':nativeRunAgent'.
      > Could not create task of type 'ClientNativeRunAgent'.
         > javafxplugin:configJavafxRun task not found.
```

If it is unclear, let me know how to clarify it.

Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated probably, but bump plugin to 0.1.38. Then you can try `./gradlew nativeRunAgent` before creating the native build

Comment: Hi José, I tried to but it has other issues. :(
```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin', version: '0.1.38']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin'.
   > Could not create task ':nativeRunAgent'.
      > Could not create task of type 'ClientNativeRunAgent'.
         > javafxplugin:configJavafxRun task not found.
```

Comment: See https://github.com/gluonhq/client-gradle-plugin, current version is 0.1.38, you should be able to use it

Comment: yes I tried. But I got this exception:

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin', version: '0.1.38']
 at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.exceptionOccurred(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:198)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: javafxplugin:configJavafxRun task not found

Comment: Do you apply the  gradle JavaFX plugin?

Comment: Hi José, yes both. You can see it up. I also updated the post when I try to apply client-gradle-plugin with version 0.1.38.

Comment: Also there is the same issue with 0.1.38: https://github.com/gluonhq/client-gradle-plugin/issues/102

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but I fixed with changing order of plugins

From:

```
id 'com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin' version '0.1.38'
id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
```

To:

```
id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'    
id 'com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin' version '0.1.38'
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Meanwhile I changed the framework. :)